# Change Step value dynamically in jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider, jquery-slide-effects

I want to add Jquery Slider with conditional step value in my project

It has minimum value 1 and maximum 100.

I want to keep Step value 1 up to slide 0 to 50 but when the slide value goes beyond 50 the step value should be 2 (Slider will increase like  48,49,50,52,54,56.........)?

How can I implement ?

This is my code

```
         this.slider = container.slider({
            animate: true,
            range: "min",
            orientation: "horizontal",
            value: self.minBet,
            max: self.maxBet,
            min: 0,
            step: self.step,  // self.step=1

            slide : function(event,ui) {
                if(self.triggerChange == true) {

                    // Here I want to chenge value of step.
                    // here self.step =1
                    // Now, If ui.value is more than 50 than step will be 2
                    self.handleChangeValue(self.slider,ui.value);
                }
            },

            change: function(event, ui) {
                if(self.triggerChange==true) {
                    self.handleChangeValue(self.slider,ui.value);
                } else {
                    self.triggerChange = true;
                }
            }

        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to provide relevant code you are using in question. A jsfiddle would be a 'plus' if you want faster help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-elegant [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNP4H/) that does what you want it to do.

It is general, so you can put in any maximum value, and any cutpoint and it will give you an even number above the cutpoint.

JS

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(){

    var slidervalue = $('#inputme').val();

    var maxvalue = 100;
    var minvalue = 0;
    var cutpoint = 50;
    var finalvalue = 0;


    if (slidervalue > 100)
    {
     slidervalue = 100;
    }
    if (slidervalue < 0)
    {
     slidervalue = 0;
    }

    if (slidervalue <= cutpoint)
    {
     finalvalue = slidervalue;
     }
      else
    {
      if( slidervalue%2 == 0 )
      {
        finalvalue = slidervalue;
       }
        else
        {
         finalvalue = 1 + +slidervalue;
         if( finalvalue > 100 )
           {
            finalvalue = 100;
            }
        }
    }
    $('.putmehere').html(finalvalue);
});
```

Comment: I have used Jquery-slider API. I need to change in API implementation not in my own logic.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with "Slider will increase like 48,49,50,52,54,56.........)?" ????

Comment: I Got answer,
We need to change step value in start method of slider api.